# How to name instance variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, name-conflict

I try to stick to the PEP8 coding conventions. I have a package called `main`. Inside the package there is a module called `time`, which has a class called `Time` inside. Now I have a bit of trouble finding a suitable name for my actual instance because `time`, which would be usually my choice, is already taken by the module and there seems to be a name-clash if I name it this way.

```
from main.time import Time

time = Time()
...
if time.status == main.time.STOPPED
```

Maybe I also placed the constant in the wrong module, but I thought that it would be better to have my constants at the place where they belong to. This is a constant used in my class `Time` (and the `main` module), so I can make sure that I don't mix it up with another constant called `STOPPED` used for player movement. Unfortunately I get an `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'time'`.

What would be the best solution here? Rename the constants to `TIME_STOPPED` and `PLAYER_STOPPED` and put them into a constants module? Naming my instance variable `my_time` or `time_` or something like this is not really what I would like to do. What's the Pythonic way?

Comment: unclear. please provide full code and traceback

Comment: Your problem is that you don't have access to `STOPPED`, surely? I think you want `from main.time import Time, STOPPED`. You could also make it a `Time` class attribute, so the test would become `if time.status == Time.STOPPED:`, further reducing ambiguity with the player version of `STOPPED`.

Comment: Try adding an import like this: `import main.time`

Comment: I would like to have to write `time.STOPPED` instead of `STOPPED`, so that I won't get confused with `player.STOPPED`. The approach making it a class member sounds good to me - so I will either change my constants being inside of the class now, or rename them and put them into a `constants` module.

Comment: You should seriously consider using more verbose names, unless you are working in a very tight scope. Short names such as `time` are ambiguous (is it the current time, a time you are waiting for, ...) and also often used already - `time` is the name of a [standard module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html).

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Since you are apparently overwriting multiple names (the code shows `time` being reused and the error hints at `main` being reused), pinpointing the problem is not possible with the code snippet you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the name `time` is a bad choice to begin with, not just because you already have a module that is named `time`, but also because there is a standard library module named `time`.

Anyways, this is not actually your problem (perhaps a clash with the STL module is, but you don't show enough code). The error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'time'` means that `main` (in `main.time`) is a *function*, not module. Your line `time = Time()` is not the cause of this, but another *function* object called `main` inside your executable.

Comment: `main.time` should be the imported module. I thought the nameclash is between that one (`main.time.STOPPED`) and the `time` instance of my Time object.. Anyways good point there - so I renamed the module to `gametime` and the class to `GameTime`. Nevertheless the problem stays the same if I use `gametime = GameTime()`. What are your names for instances.. Maybe I should use gametime_instance or game_time then to avoid the nameclash...

Comment: @freeDom- I can only reiterate that your naming of the `Time` or `GameTime` instance is questionable but *not* the issue. You have a *function* called `main` in your application's scope which shadows the `main` module.

Comment: Oh.. So thats the one? Yes, inside my `__init__` module there I have a `main` function.. Maybe the module name `main` also is a very bad idea...